# UPSERT synonym for MERGE?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

I created a tag [upsert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upsert) (7x) today and wrote a somewhat useful (I hope) tag wiki.

Later I found that there is already a tag [merge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merge) (15x, no wiki). Would you consider the two synonymous? I can't mark them as such, my score for [merge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merge) is too low.

Comment: I think that there is a discussion amongst the folks in the field as to if this is "reasonable syntax" for most devs, because the underlying mechanics can be quite distinct. Let's not be rash, but I do hope to see a discussion on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No they are not synonymous.

An `UPSERT` can be implemented without using the `MERGE` keyword and conversely `UPSERT` is just one possible use case for `MERGE` (when it has both a `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED  [ BY TARGET ] THEN INSERT ...`)

At least in SQL Server [it is not required](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) that `MERGE` have both (or indeed either) of these clauses.

The following use of `MERGE` neither updates nor inserts.

```
CREATE TABLE T(A INT)

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1),(2),(3);

MERGE INTO T
USING (VALUES (1),
              (2)) S(A)
ON T.A = S.A
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  DELETE;
```

Other (possibly SQL Server centric) use cases for Merge that have nothing to do with Upserts is [inserting `DEFAULT VALUES` for multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863711/73226) or [Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)

Comment: So there are obviously subtly differences. Should we have two separate tags? It would seem they fit into the same class of questions, especially since those who seek advice might not be aware of the details.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I think they have to be separate tags rather than synonymized or people searching the upsert tag could end up with a whole load of irrelevant results that are nothing to do with upserts but are to do with alternate uses of `MERGE`.

Comment: +1 for separate tags. There is overlap between upsert and merge, but easily enough difference IMHO to prevent synonymization (!)

Comment: Similar non-Update/Insert functionality exists in Oracle for Merge.

Comment: `UPSERT` could be considered a subset of `MERGE`, but not synonymous.  Perhaps their wiki entries should reflect this.

Comment: I updated the tag wiki for `UPSERT` with results from this discussion.