# Revisiting upsert vs merge

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

[Back in 2013](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/906/upsert-synonym-for-merge) we decided that [upsert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upsert) and [merge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merge) are two different things and questions about such should be tagged separately.

Today Postgres has `insert ... on conflict`, and [upsert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upsert) has mostly historical Postgres questions, while new [questions about "insert ... on conflict"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=insert%20on%20conflict) are for the most part not tagged with any specific tag about this feature.

One view is that tags should be more generic so that users not knowing exactly what they are looking for can find things -- for example users knowing syntax/concept/feature from one DBMS looking for help about that on another, bearing in mind that searching for a specific DBMS often requires eg "Postgres" or [postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgres). In this scenario we could make [upsert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upsert) and [merge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merge) synonyms, and add something like [insert-on-conflict](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-on-conflict) as a synonym too.

In the other view we keep tags as specific as possible, probably with links to other tags in their descriptions and wiki entries. In this case we add [insert-on-conflict](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-on-conflict) as a separate tag, and all questions about "inserting if new, updating if existing" on modern versions of Postgres should probably be tagged with this.

Answer (score 6):

I'd be inclined towards the latter - keep the tags as specific as possible.

Then, if a user isn't sure/makes a mistake/whatever, it'd most likely be picked up by experienced users who could add/delete the relevant tags!

Just my €0.02 (pity there's no € cent symbol...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I would like to do the synonyms, but I like [insert-on-conflict](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-on-conflict) for sure.

While there may be mostly postgres questions, the concept of a [upsert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upsert) isn't particularly only-postgres